# Speedup selecting subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to select subset of pandas dataframe and compute some statistics, but it's painfully slow, maybe it can be done faster?

```
column_name1_set = df.column_name1.unique()
column_name2_set = df.column_name2.unique()

for i, name1 in enumerate(column_name1_set):
    for name2 in column_name2_set:
        df_t = df[(df['column_name1']==int(name1)) & (df['column_name2']==name2)]
        s = df_t.sum(axis=0)
        s['amount_min'] = df_t['amount'].min()
        s['amount_max'] = df_t['amount'].max()
        s['amount_mean'] = df_t['amount'].mean()
        s['amount_median'] = df_t['amount'].median()

        #store s ...
```

Comment: can you provide a sample data ? You can make it superfast.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.groupby(['column_name1','column_name2']).sum()['amount'].agg(['min','max','mean','median'])
```